# angularjs webapi signalR chatbox like bookmyshow

Tags: c#, sql, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

i need a live chat box for my application. i should be used for the customers. and it should contain auto reply for some predefined questions. i am using angularjs and asp.net webapi. please help me out.

Comment: welcome to SO. Please specify what exactly you need. Also, share the efforts you have put into this issue before asking questions

Comment: Hi, thank you for you response. we are creating sellers e-commers application. in our application we want to create an live chat module. and also it should send auto reply for some predefined questions to the users. we arre using angularjs webapi and signalR in our application.

Answer (score 0):

1st Option is you can set up SignalR with Web Api to send the auto replies from server to client automatically by subscribing to SignalR Server methods from angular, and append the received replies in DOM.

2nd Option is you build a console app to host your chat server built on top of SignalR and directly subscribe to it events from client browsers, console application will be hosted as an application providing you with the facility to subscribe to its events using web sockets or signalR whatever you feel comfortable with.

Comment: Here is a good article that can help you start with 2nd option of creating a selft host Application https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host